# CoCreateInstance Attempts to Load 64-bit Version of DLL Even Though App is 32-bit

Tags: scheduled-tasks

My application interfaces with Task Manager. The code that handles this thus loads mstask.dll. The problem I have is that my application (which is 32-bit) fails on Windows 7 64-bit with the error message "%1 is not a valid win32 application".

Using a map file and some stack tracing I have determined that this error message is triggered when CoCreateInstance is called with the GUID of the Task Scheduling Service. By using Process Monitor from SysInternals I was able to determine that my application is actually trying to load C:\Windows\system32\mstask.dll instead of C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\mstask.dll which is the 32-bit version of mstask.dll.

The reason for the error message is thus that the application tries to load C:\Windows\system32\mstask.dll which is a 64-bit DLL, which will obviously not work from my 32-bit app.

Does anyone know any reason why CoCreateInstance would not correctly load the 32-bit version of mstask.dll? Obviously SYSWOW64 redirection is not working properly.

The strange thing is that I have created a small test app that just attempts to initialize the Task Scheduler service. In this test app the CoCreateInstance call succeeds without any problem. So something about my real application must be different, but I have no idea what.

Any and all input is appreciated!

Comment: No, it's a standard win32 executable

Comment: So much for that idea. :) I sounds like the system thinks it is 64 bit for some reason but I'm really just guessing.

Comment: It does indeed sound that way, but all the other DLLs loaded by the app are loaded correctly from SYSWOW64. I cannot understand why a CoCreateInstance call would attempt to load a DLL in system32 when all other DLLs loaded by the app are from SYSWOW64.

Comment: Ok, some more information! I have placed a call to a function that ends up calling CoCreateInstance in the startup code for my app. NOW, surprisingly, the later calls work! So it seems that the redirection is working when my app is starting, but not later. I suspect my app does something that breaks SYSWOW64 redirection after it has started. But this seems to be a temporary workaround.

Comment: It does sound like WOW64 is broken, can you use a debugger to break on `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` or `Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection` and see if it is actually some rogue code disabling and not turning it back on.